# Letters are not captured inside quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find the attributes of `HTML` tags. Regular expression works corectly. But, data is not captured.

My regex:

```
/\<(\w*)\s+[(\w*)(?=\=\".*\")\s+]+\>/
```

Sample input:

```
<a href="sdfds" val="fdf">
```

Regular expression is working fine. But, the text inside the capturing groups of  `[]` which is `\w*` are not captured.

Help me solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't capture within sets.

Comment: Also you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, then how to do that. Plese let me know correct way to do.

Comment: @dnit13, I am not trying to validate complete HTML. I know that we can't do it using regex. Ijust want to solve the above mentioned small problem.

Comment: Do you want just the attribute or the tagname too?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, both